# Android custom view - Error with custom attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a project in Eclipse that I use as a library (I export it as a jar and import the jar in the rest of the projects.

I want to add a custom Button View with the methods enabled/disabled that will change the background to one that I want to specify in the layout (XML)

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/) but when I export the apk I got this error:

**error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'disabledBG' in package 'com.xxx.library'**

this is the attrs.xml file I have in my library project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="MyButton">
        <attr format="integer" name="disabledBG" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

and then on my application project (com.xxx.app.yyy), I have this in the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx.library"
[...]
    <com.xxx.library.View.MyButton
                android:id="@+id/menuMap"
                style="@style/SHGreenButtons"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                mylib:disabledBG="@drawable/disabled_buttons"
                android:onClick="goMap"
                android:text="@string/menu_map" />
[...]
```

Also when I go to */gen/com.symbios.library/R.java* there's *R.attr.disabledBG*

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

P.S. When I exported the library as jar, I included the **src**, **gen** and **res** folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong with your project configuration.
You shouldn't use a jar lib if you have the opportunity to link to the project.

Please take a look at this article : 
[click here](http://mdbsoftwares.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-share-ressources-between.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I just did what you said and still not working.. do you think my xml namespace is wrong? xmlns:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx.library"

Comment: yes ! use the android instead :

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx.library"`

Comment: That will mess up with the rest of the layout.. I'm using both as I saw in the tutorial

Comment: Nop, because you linked with the library project, so the sources are in your project. Try it ;)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I was understandable : use only 1 xmlns.

Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4696/discussion-between-serpro-and-harry)